# CRITICAL! Failed to get host list

Tags: distcc

DistCC is apparently failing to connect to hosts.

```
$ distcc --show-hosts
distcc[32060] (dcc_parse_hosts) Warning: /home/amacdonald/.distcc/zeroconf/hosts contained no hosts; can't distribute work
distcc[32060] (dcc_zeroconf_add_hosts) CRITICAL! failed to parse host file.

distcc[32060] (dcc_show_hosts) CRITICAL! Failed to get host list
```

My default configuration is

```
$ cat /etc/default/distcc | grep -v "\#\|^$"
STARTDISTCC="true"
ALLOWEDNETS="127.0.0.1"
LISTENER="127.0.0.1"
NICE="10"
JOBS=""
ZEROCONF="true"
```

I thought ZeroConf didn't need me to configure the hosts, but it is complaining that I haven't. If I try to write hostnames into `/home/amacdonald/.distcc/zeroconf/hosts` distcc actually ends up deleting these rows.

Also, the system I am on is,

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
$ dpkg -l | grep distcc
ii  distcc                                                3.1-6                                               amd64        simple distributed compiler client and server
$ distcc --version
distcc 3.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  (protocols 1, 2 and 3) (default port 3632)
  built May  9 2013 23:15:01
Copyright (C) 2002, 2003, 2004 by Martin Pool.
Includes miniLZO (C) 1996-2002 by Markus Franz Xaver Johannes Oberhumer.
Portions Copyright (C) 2007-2008 Google.

distcc comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  distcc is free software, and
you may use, modify and redistribute it under the terms of the GNU 
General Public License version 2 or later.

Built with Zeroconf support.

Please report bugs to distcc@lists.samba.org
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a bit late, but I was just trying to do the exact same thing and what worked for me, and what I find curious in your distcc file are the following lines.

```
ALLOWEDNETS="127.0.0.1"
```

I thought this had to be a subnet mask, e.g. *192.168.0.0/16*. The loopback address (127.0.0.1) routes back packets to the host, AFAIK.

```
LISTENER="127.0.0.1"
```

I thought, this had to be the IP Address of this PC itself, (the one that is going to help in the compilation process), e.g. *192.168.13.13*. (At least for me, right now, that was the error. As soon as I changed it, this 'helper' PC started accepting compile jobs from the hosts.)

```
JOBS=""
```

This one maybe irrelevant, but a non-zero integer there would leave nothing to chance (rather than having to look into the documentation, that what the default value for *JOBS* is). But probably its Ok.

> I thought ZeroConf didn't need me to configure the hosts, but it is
>   complaining that I haven't. If I try to write hostnames into
>   /home/amacdonald/.distcc/zeroconf/hosts distcc actually ends up
>   deleting these rows.

So IMHO, the above changes are needed irrespective of ZeroConf. *(But I maybe wrong.)*

Comment: I'll check the subnet. I could have sworn I changed it